# What is the another way to declare string in specflow step definition instead of (.*)?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, bdd, specflow, gherkin

Currently i am using (`.*`) for the specflow string, and now there is a requirement to use another way.What is the another way for string representation in specflow instead of (`.*`).Can anybody help me on this?

Comment: Put backtickcks ` (the button that is with the ~ key on US Keyboards) around the `.*` to make the text not italic. You could also highlight the text and press the button on the toolbar that looks like `{ }`

Comment: Any regex will do; `.*` is just the default. See [here](http://joebuschmann.com/useful-regex-for-specflow-bindings/) for some examples.

Comment: You could do something like `"([^"])"` - matches anything within double quotes that isn't itself a double quote, captures the stuff within the double quotes

Comment: Thanks jeroen Mostert and Kyle Fairms